# azure - what are requests to 'eusaaomssa.blob.core.windows.net' for?

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-security

I see in the logs that my VM tries to reach this storage account `eusaaomssa.blob.core.windows.net`. What is this for? I can't find it anywhere in the docs, not even google can find it anywhere.

Comment: Have you perhaps enabled this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-enable-overview? I'm just guessing since the name contains "oms" (operations management suite), which was renamed to Azure Monitor now.

Comment: yes, I did. I allowed 'eusaaomssa.blob.core.windows.net' for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be assured that there are no security risks. This storage account should be created when you perform an operation. It is not an external or built-in account. If you really want to know why it exists, you can contact Azure VM Support for further confirmation.